# How do you get the first element out of a JSON String without knowing the name of the element in FileMaker 16 or 17?

Tags: json, filemaker

I had an issue today with Filemaker on how to get the first element out of a json result without knowing the key.

Example $json result from an API call

```
{
    "26298070": {
        "task_id": "26298070",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "name": "DEPOT-0045 Research ODBC Model Extraction via Django To cut down on development time from Filemaker to Postgres",
        "external_task_id": "32c8fd51-2066-42b9-b88b-8a2275fafc3f",
        "external_parent_id": "64e7c829-d88e-48ae-9ba4-bb7a3871a7ce",
        "level": "1",
        "add_date": "2018-06-04 21:45:16",
        "archived": "0",
        "color": "#34C644",
        "tags": "DEPOT-0045",
        "budgeted": "1",
        "checked_date": null,
        "root_group_id": "91456",
        "assigned_to": null,
        "assigned_by": null,
        "due_date": null,
        "note": "",
        "context": null,
        "folder": null,
        "repeat": null,
        "billable": "0",
        "budget_unit": "hours",
        "public_hash": null,
        "modify_time": null
    }
}
```

I tried JSONGetElement( $json, "") and got the original json.
I tried JSONGetElement( $json, ".") and got the original json.
I tried JSONGetElement( $json, 1 ) and got nothing.

How do you get the first element out of a JSON String without knowing the name of the element in FileMaker 16 or 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the root element:

> **JSONListKeys** ( $json ; "" )

result: *26298070*
Once you get the root, you can get the child keys.

Comment: I still like this answer and it fails if there is more than one top-level element. To get around this I went back to using MIddleWords.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered that FileMaker has a function to extract words from text so I thought I'd see what happened if I extracted the first word as a key.

I tried

```
JSONGetElement ( $json ; MiddleWords ( $json,1,1 ) )
```

and got the result I was looking for.

```
{
    "add_date": "2018-06-04 21:45:16",
    "archived": "0",
    "assigned_by": null,
    "assigned_to": null,
    "billable": "0",
    "budget_unit": "hours",
    "budgeted": "1",
    "checked_date": null,
    "color": "#34C644",
    "context": null,
    "due_date": null,
    "external_parent_id": "64e7c829-d88e-48ae-9ba4-bb7a3871a7ce",
    "external_task_id": "32c8fd51-2066-42b9-b88b-8a2275fafc3f",
    "folder": null,
    "level": "1",
    "modify_time": null,
    "name": "DEPOT-0045 Research ODBC Model Extraction via Django To cut down on development time from Filemaker to Postgres",
    "note": "",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "public_hash": null,
    "repeat": null,
    "root_group_id": "91456",
    "tags": "DEPOT-0045",
    "task_id": "26298070"
}
```

which makes it easy to parse simple JSON schema's that use attributes for keys.